# pants build store git metadata inside pex

Tags: python, pex, pants

is there a way to create a git metadata like (git commit #, branch , tag etc.,) in the pex file generated with Pants build ? if not , is there a way to hook into the goal of the pants build, so that i can generate the file which will then be packaged.

Comment: did you find out the answer? I just asked a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35756339/473672

Comment: And I just posted a good-enough-for-me answer, which may or may not help somebody else: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35826002/473672