# --version support in a Python program built with Pants

Tags: python, pants

How can I get [Pants](https://pantsbuild.github.io/) to store the output of `git describe` somewhere in my `.pex` file so that I can access it from the Python code I'm writing?

Basically I want to be able to clone [my project](https://github.com/walles/px) and do this:

1. `./pants binary px`
2. Distribute the resulting `dist/px.pex` to somebody
3. That somebody should be able to do `px.pex --version` and get a printout of whatever `git describe` said when I built the `.pex` in step one.

Help!

Comment: Why the downvote? A clarification would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `pex` already does `git describe` on build. The result it stores in a `PEX-INFO` file in the root of the `.pex` file. So to read it, I did this:

```
def get_version():
    """Extract version string from PEX-INFO file"""
    my_pex_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(my_pex_name)
    with zip.open("PEX-INFO") as pex_info:
        return json.load(pex_info)['build_properties']['tag']
```

This is good enough IMO, but there are also drawbacks. If somebody has an improved answer I'm prepared to switch to that one as the accepted one.

Outages with this one:

- Relies on relative paths to locate `PEX-INFO`, would be better if there was some kind of API call for this.
- No way to customize how the version number is computed; I'd like to do `git describe --dirty` for example.